# autocomplete source from Outlook address book

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox, outlook

My application has an E-mail address field (textbox) for which I would like to load in a custom AutoComplete source from Outlook. Any suggestions or resources on how to do this?

The loading of the address book into the custom source will probably occur on the form load and I will assign the custom source to that textbox there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [Outlook Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780.aspx) successfully before for working with Outlook.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184654.aspx) example shows how to enumerate through all entries in the address book and you should be able to use it as a starting point. In particular, this line will output the name and email address that you'll be needing to populate the autocomplete textbox.

```
Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = addrEntry.GetExchangeUser();
Debug.WriteLine(exchUser.Name + " " + exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress);
```

As for the autocomplete portion, check out [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: arg i'm having difficulty getting microsoft's example code to work. com issue, profile issue, application session issue. are we sure there's not a simpler way to merely read in just the email addresses in outlook?

Comment: Not that I know of. It shouldn't be that hard to use. All I had to do was reference the Outlook dll and I was able to paste the code in as is.