# Outlook - How to access the auto-complete address list

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to be able to access the auto-complete address list that appears when typing into either the TO,CC or BCC lines within an email. I wish to be able to extract this data similarly to how I access other address lists within Outlook.

Would anyone be able to confirm if this is possible and if so how I could go about doing it.

This is currently how I'm extracting email addresses various other address lists.

```
foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry item in addressList.AddressEntries)
    {
        using (item.ComDisposable())
           {
               switch (item.AddressEntryUserType)
                   {
                       case Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry:
                       case Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry:
                           var exUser = item.GetExchangeUser();
                           Debug.WriteLine(exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress, "_GetOutlookContacts");
                           yield return new EGContact(exUser.Name, exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress, item.ID);
                           break;

                       case Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olOutlookContactAddressEntry:
                            var contact = item.GetContact();
                            yield return new EGContact(contact.FullName, contact.Email1Address, item.ID);
                            break;

                       case Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry:
                       break;

                       default:
                       break;

                  }
          }
    }
```

Comment: I thik this might be helpful: 1 - [Information about the Outlook AutoComplete list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2199226); 2 - [Implementing Outlook email send to Autocomplete in a windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522296/implementing-outlook-email-send-to-autocomplete-in-a-windows-form) and 3 - [autocomplete source from Outlook address book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198818/autocomplete-source-from-outlook-address-book)

Comment: @MaciejLos thank you for your comment, the 3rd looked promising but seems to be more orientated about creating an auto-complete source whereas I want to extract contacts from Outlooks auto-complete list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete stream is stored as a hidden (associated) message with the message class of "IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete" in the Inbox folder. You can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author): go to the Inbox folder, click IMAPIFolder button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the "Associated Contents" tab, locate a message with PR_MESSAGE_CLASS == "IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", select the PR_ROAMING_BINARYSTREAM property to see its contents.

You can open that message using the Outlook Object Model (`MAPIFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass`), read the property using `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`, then parse it. Note that large autocomplete streams cannot be opened using PropertyAccessor.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) an option (I am also its author), it exposes autocomplete as the [RDONicknames](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdonicknames.htm) collection:

```
 set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
 set Nicknames = Session.GetNicknames
 for each NickName in NickNames
     Debug.Print NickName.Name & " - " & NickName.SmtpAddress
 next
```

Comment: You answered this question 4+ years before I asked!  You always deliver :)
You can guess what I'll be using Redemption for today

Answer (score 1):

In an earlier version of Outlook, this information was stored in local .NK2 files. In Outlook 2010 and up, this information is stored in your mailbox (AutoComplete Stream). See [Clearing AutoComplete and other Recipient Caches](http://blog.enowsoftware.com/solutions-engine/bid/184025/Clearing-AutoComplete-and-other-Recipient-Caches) for more information.

You can use the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-recipients-property-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) collection (see the corresponding property of the MailItem class) for accessing the data entered to the To, Cc or Bcc fields.